# Applet JDBC Connection Failed on Client Machine

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, applet

My self-signed applet perfectly works on applet viewer and my local web browser. However, when I change connection strings according to the db name, user and password for the mysql database on the website's server and upload the project to the server via ftp, the applet cannot connect to the database. The applet code is:

```
public void init() {
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add( new JLabel("Start"));
revalidate();
// TODO start asynchronous download of heavy resources
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://www.mywebiste.com:3306/database";
String user = "user";
String password = "password";


try {
    Class.forName(driver);                        
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

    String sql4 = "Select * from form where Il='Ankara'";

                    //System.out.println(password + " " + userName);
               Statement  stmt = con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql4);
    panel.add( new JLabel("Connection"));
    revalidate();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    panel.add( new JLabel("Not Connected"));
    revalidate();
}

Container content = getContentPane();
             content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
             content.add(panel);
```

}

Comment: could you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: and why do you use an applet? it doen't make any sense in my opinion. try using a jar oder java webstart

Comment: It is not a web application, so it does not have a stacktrace

Comment: It has to be an applet, I did not decide that and I have to make it work

Comment: you can read the stacktrace in the java console of your browser.

Comment: It says:console.trace()
(anonymous function)
InjectedScript._evaluateOn
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
InjectedScript.evaluate

Answer (score 1):

You're the victim of the same-origin policy.

There are ways around this by signing the applet but I would strongly recommend not to bother. With all the security issues in Java lately involving Applets and JNLP, this technology is as dead as the dodo. More and more systems come default with java applets disabled and more users are disabling this themselves (or their IT departments).

Best to go with some lightweight REST service in your webapp on the server and some javascript on the browser (or an applet if you really insist) which uses these services over http. Then you also do not need to expose the database to the network.

Even for an internal app I would give serious thought about it (or pushback to whoever is asking).

Comment: The applet is already signed and working in local browser in my computer. I have to get it working. I could not understand what the problem is, it should work by just chaning the connection information and uploading it via ftp to the client machine of the website which is again a localhost.

Comment: Is this a school assignment??? If so they seriously need to review the curriculum and teaching staff. Whatever, since you're hell bent on punishment check that all jars of the application are signed. Make sure that the browser accepts the certificate used to sign the jars. Do not forget that localhost is the computer term for "me" and in the case of the applet means the computer of the browser. Check the security settings of the Java Control Panel on the browser computer. And post the stacktrace from the Java Console in the browser.